# How to properly display a primitive value in of an object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
import java.util.*;
public class Student 
{
static CollegeCourse[] theirCourses = new CollegeCourse[5];

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int ID;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////// Assigns student ID
    System.out.println("Please enter your student ID >>");
        ID  = input.nextInt();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////// Wasn't sure how to populate the array
        theirCourses[0] = new CollegeCourse("CIS 110", 3, 'A'); 
        theirCourses[1] = new CollegeCourse("MATH 330", 2, 'A');
        theirCourses[2] = new CollegeCourse("FR ENG 110", 2, 'A');
        theirCourses[3] = new CollegeCourse("PHYSICS 110", 1, 'B');
        theirCourses[4] = new CollegeCourse("GAMING 110", 1, 'C');


    theirCourses[0].setCID("CIS 110");
    theirCourses[1].setCID("MATH 330");
    theirCourses[2].setCID("FR ENG 110");
    theirCourses[3].setCID("PHYSICS 110");
    theirCourses[4].setCID("GAMING 110");

    theirCourses[0].setHours(3);
    theirCourses[1].setHours(2);
    theirCourses[2].setHours(2);
    theirCourses[3].setHours(1);
    theirCourses[4].setHours(1);

    theirCourses[0].setGrade('A');
    theirCourses[1].setGrade('A');
    theirCourses[2].setGrade('A');
    theirCourses[3].setGrade('B');
    theirCourses[4].setGrade('C');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Displays all preset populated courses
        System.out.println("Please enter a number for the course you would to view, 0-4.\n" 
                + "Courses are:");
for(int x = 0; x < theirCourses.length; ++ x)
     {
        System.out.println(theirCourses[x].getCID());

     }
}
}
```

If I don't have the repetitious statements populating the array below where I already assign the array theirCourses a String, int, and char all in one line then when I get to the bottom where I have the print statement:  System.out.println(theirCourses[x].getCID()); I keep getting a null output. Any clue as to what may be the cause of that? I will post the client class as well.

```
public class CollegeCourse 
{
private String cID;
private int cHours;
private char grade;

public CollegeCourse(String string, int i, char c) 
{

}

public void setCID(String c)
{
    cID = c;
}

public String getCID()
{
    return cID;
}

public void setHours(int h)
{
    cHours = h;
}

public int getHours()
{
    return cHours;
}

public void setGrade(char g)
{
    grade = g;
}

public char getGrade()
{
    return grade;
}


}
```

Comment: Well, look at the constructor. It doesn't do anything with its arguments (which are very badly named, BTW).

Comment: @captaindex Are you getting `null` output even with the repititive assignment?

Comment: After adding a couple of closing brackets in Student.java, this code ran successfully on my workstation. @captaindex, can you post your output?

Comment: @Java Guy next door You know what, I didn't put the closing brackets in on accident. Yes, I know it runs, but I wanted to know why it won't run after all the repetitious code is removed.

Comment: @captaindex "why it won't run after"... because your constructor doesn't do anything. Assign to the class variables within the constructor, and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JB Nizet mentioned, your constructor is not doing anything. Constructor is taking the parameters, set them as the value.

```
public CollegeCourse(String string, int i, char c) {
    cID = string;
    cHours = i;
    grade = c;
}
```

Get rid of all the setCID, setHours and setGrade. That's 15 lines of unnecessary code.